# Error terms for repeated measures ANOVA with among-subjects factors

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

What's the formula to calculate a sum of squares for the interaction between subjects S (nested within an among-subjects factor A) and a within-subjects factor B when there are other within-subjects factors? (This would be the error term for within-subjects factor B, B×(S|A).)

My stats book just glosses over it and I can't find a good online reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

It's the sum of the interaction term sum of squares for an ANOVA calculated within each among-factor level.

That is, given among factor A, subjects S, and within factors B and C:

1. Split the data by among-factor levels.
2. Perform an ANOVA within each set.
3. Sum the interaction terms B×S to get B×(S|A).
4. Sum the interaction terms C×S to get C×(S|A).
5. Sum the interaction terms B×C×S to get B×C×(S|A).
6. These are the error terms for overall factors B/B×A, C/C×A, and A×B×C, respectively.